# minipage has overfull hbox

Tags: boxes, minipage, tabu

I'm struggling with this piece of LaTeX code:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {>{\itshape}r c}
        Foo:&\makebox[5cm]{}\\
        \cline{2-2}\\[-0.5em]
        & Foo
    \end{tabu}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {>{\itshape}r c}
        Bar:&\makebox[5cm]{}\\
        \cline{2-2}\\[-0.5em]
        & Bar
    \end{tabu}
\end{minipage}
```

It has an overfull hbox of `17.62482pt too wide`, just to the right of the minipages (see screenshot below). I can fix it by setting the width to `0.45\textwidth`, but that's obviously not the right way.

[image: Overfull hbox in black at the right hand side]

How do I pin down what is causing this? Or is there some obvious error in my code that I am missing?

Comment: Are you using `\noindent` at the beginning?

Comment: No. Would it be a good idea to do so?

Comment: Just try it before the 1st `minipage`.

Comment: `\noindent is indeed enough.

Comment: Yes, that did solve it. Why, and how could I have known it?

Comment: @lindhe It happens because any paragraph starts with a `\parindent`. So you have to pull it back to the left margin. How would you know? With experience. Read and read and try.

Comment: Ah. Right. I didn't think that stuff that is not text starts a new paragraph. Thank you. Would you like to post this as an answer, and I'll make you the honor of accepting that answer.

Comment: Another debugging aid is the showframe package (or showframe option of geometry).

Comment: I had the same problem, but in my case \noindent did not fix it and the black box only appears in draft mode :S. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sigur pointed out the answer in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287836/minipage-has-overfull-hbox#comment696138_287836):

Every paragraph is indented as default. Since the minipage begins a new paragraph it too will be indented. This behaviour can be prohibited by putting `\noindent` just before the new paragraph (the minipage environment), or by using `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}` in the top matter.