# Overfull hbox in minipage environment with itemize

Tags: graphics, itemize, minipage

I would like to place a bullet list next to an image. So I've done the following :

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}         % languages rules
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % text encoding
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, 
            bottom=2.5cm, 
            inner=2.5cm, 
            outer=3cm, 
            twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}               % optional arguments to the \includegraphics command
\usepackage{float}                  % Improves the interface for defining floating objects such as figures and tables.
\usepackage[lofdepth,               % Faire des sous-figures
            lotdepth]{subfig}    
\usepackage{enumitem}               % Personalized list

%\insertImage[position]{image_path}{scale}{Figure_title}{label}
\newcommand{\insertImage}[5][center]{
  \begin{#1}
  \includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth]{#2}
  \captionof{figure}{#4} 
  \label{#5}
  \end{#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
        \noindent
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Node
            \item Endpoint
            \item Service
            \item Pod 
            \item Ingress
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.8\textwidth}
        \insertImage{monitoring}{1}{CEE monitoring}{fig-monitoring}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

But when I compile I got the following warning : Overfull \hbox (2.43332pt too wide) in paragraph

I do not understand this warning as the two minipages are supposed to be 1\textwidth.
Based on this : [minipage has overfull hbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287836/minipage-has-overfull-hbox)
Using \noindent is supposed to fixed the problem but this doesn't work.

And the two minipages are not aligned :

[image]

Do you guys know how I could have that bullet list and this image at the same height ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: a minipage is positioned like a letter you have a paragraph indent, a .2\textwidth box a word-space and a .8\textwidth box so they do not fit.  use `\noindent` before the first, and remove the space between the minipages

Comment: The word space between the minipage is the line break ?
I try to paste together ```\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}``` I have the same result ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to beware adding white space before and between the minipages.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}         % languages rules
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % text encoding
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, 
            bottom=2.5cm, 
            inner=2.5cm, 
            outer=3cm, 
            twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}               % optional arguments to the \includegraphics command
\usepackage{float}                  % Improves the interface for defining floating objects such as figures and tables.
\usepackage[lofdepth,               % Faire des sous-figures
            lotdepth]{subfig}    
\usepackage{enumitem}               % Personalized list

%\insertImage[position]{image_path}{scale}{Figure_title}{label}
\newcommand{\insertImage}[5][center]{
  \begin{#1}
  \includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth]{#2}
  \captionof{figure}{#4} 
  \label{#5}
  \end{#1}
}

\begin{document}

%no indent here
\noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
% not this        \noindent
        \vspace{0pt}% something to top align on
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Node
            \item Endpoint
            \item Service
            \item Pod 
            \item Ingress
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%no space here
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.8\textwidth}
        \vspace{0pt}% something to top align on
        \insertImage{example-image}{1}{CEE monitoring}{fig-monitoring}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer David it worked :)